# Boolean check on fields returning any of them except if all have same value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Assuming we have 4 boolean fields a,b,c,d

How can we return any of the fields that are true, but not nothing when all 4 are true?

`where a=true or b=true or c=true or d=true`

will return a row where even all 4 fields are set tot true. How can I exclude this row from the query?

Same would apply if searched value is `false`

Comment: Extra point: it **does not matter** if you search for `true` or `false`. The answer (query and result) are the same ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
where (true in (a,b,c,d)
       and (a,b,c,d) <> (true,true,true,true));
```

Which can be simplified (suggested by [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9)) to:

```
where true in (a,b,c,d) and false in (a,b,c,d)
```

Note that it will not handle NULL values properly. If you want that as well, you will need to use `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a direct translation of "not when all 4 are true" into SQL:

```
where NOT(a=true AND b=true AND c=true AND d=true)
```

Edit:

@a_horse_with_no_name shortened it further to

```
where NOT(a AND b AND c AND d)
```

Edit2:

This doesn't work correctly (will return a row when all four columns are false), so mixing with @a_horse_with_no_name's answer:

```
where NOT(a AND b AND c AND d) AND (a OR b OR c OR d)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using [Postgres aggregate functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) that I thought would work but actually **doesn't!**
  (don't try this):

```
where bool_or(a, b, c, d) and not bool_and(a, b, c, d)
```

This will work but is much more verbose than the other answers:

```
where exists 
     (select 1
      from (values (a), (b), (c), (d)) as b(i)
      having bool_or(i) and not bool_and(i) 
     )
```

(somewhat simplified):

```
where (select bool_or(i) and not bool_and(i) 
       from (values (a), (b), (c), (d)) as b(i)
      )
```

---

This however, works. It's based on `FALSE < TRUE` ordering:

```
where greatest(a,b,c,d) = true and least(a,b,c,d) = false
```

or:

```
where greatest(a,b,c,d) and not least(a,b,c,d)
```

or just:

```
where greatest(a,b,c,d) > least(a,b,c,d)
```